# How did HP made their power on bottom work with no VSB (standby) on their pro 290 and to make a 24pin ATX psu work with it?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, atx, proprietary, hp

The factory psu is a psu with RuRach board and has two ATX 4pin and 3 of 7 inline mini:

[image: A picture of this new proprietary power connectors by HP]

From HP site, the full 7pin inline mini of the p2:

[image: The pinout of 7 of 7 inline mini]

Apparently,
green is for PS_ON;
grey, for PWR_OK;
black, for GRND;
purple, for +VSB (12v, probably?);
white, for FanCMD;
red, for FanSPEED.

What I've thought is that without a standby signal, the PSU shouldn't be able to start by clicking on the power-on bottom on the motherboard, but **it not only works but also has no on/off switch**. My search is taking me to info far beyond my knowledge, that it could be "single sided" not "vestigial".

So **at first, how?**

And lastly, would connecting the 9th pin of a standard 24pin ATX (+5VSB) to the now empty 6th pin of the mini inline and onto the motherboard (regardless of the possibility of needing to be stepped up for now) mitigate this?
Meaning that this way a standard 24-pin ATX psu would be able to be started by such proprietary system, or would it work regardless of status of VSB on the ATX psu in the first place? Am I missing something?

Basically, **how can I make a 24pin atx psu work?**

Comment: You should double check voltages with a multimeter, but from how I understand the PSUs, they use the same 12V lines for the stand-by voltage. This makes them not 
compatible with ATX, but you can do things to make it work. You connect the grey, and black wires to get power-ok and ground. And then short green/power-on with black/gnd to turn the ATX psu permanently on. The p4 connectors are 12V and Ground so connect them accordingly. The mobo now should have the V it needs, and it should be able to turn on/off with the button and software. The ATX should have a button of its own to turn it off

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I "hack the HP PSU.. I just buy a 24 pin adapter off amazon, doesn't really matter what it for because you'll be cutting the one end off. The only reason I use these is so I'm not splicing into my standard ATX psu wires incase I want to use it in another build later. Then all I do is wire the Grey and the black wire from the P2 pin to the grey and black wires on the 24 pin adapter. You could then just wire the green wire and a ground to a external switch on your case to turn the 'stand by power on ' but if your atx psu has a switch on it directly and most do. What I do is just solder the green wire and a black wire together. then just split the x2 4 pin 12v cpu wires from your atx psu and plug one into each of the 4 pin plugs on the motherboard and boom should work. The only caveat is that you have the make sure after you shut down your pc in windows that you 'switch off' your psu with either the switch you added or the one on the back of the psu depending on how you decided to wire it up. The HP psu provides constant stand by power that the motherboard detects and can turn 'on or off ' the psu. Your atx psu wont have that function so that is why you'll need to either provide you own or just jumper the green power on wire with a ground and then just use the switch on the back of the psu to actually 'shutoff or turn on the psu'. Then just don't forget to flip the switch to provide the 12 v to the motherboard before hitting the power button on the case to turn on the computer. Out side of having to manually switch the psu on and off everything else works as it should. Sorry if none of that makes sense but it's 1 am and I just got off a 18 hour shift so If you need anymore help just post here and i'll be glad to break it down better.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. That is a tad difficult to read. [Editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1771298/edit) the question and dividing it to smaller paragraphs would make it much clearer.